# how to call two time the same directive with the change in HTML belongs to the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a project using **angularJS** material. I'm calling a directive(`<sdiv-panel></sdiv-panel>`) two time in a DOM but the problem is if I modify some element in the HTML of the directive, the second call of the same directive return a new HTML.

How can I solve this?

I'm looking for solutions that makes me call the directive with all the changes in the HTML page belongs to the directive that i call.

**My code:**

```
<md-content style="height:-webkit-calc(100% - 64px)"  flex class="stop-scrolling"  md-theme="{{vm.contentTheme}}" md-theme-watch="true">       
    <div style="height:-webkit-calc(50%)" layout="column" ng-repeat="cardrow in vm.cards" ng-show="vm.multipleview">         
        <div flex layout="row" layout-fill>           
            <md-card class="card" ng-repeat="card in cardrow"  >             
                <md-toolbar style="min-height:35px; height:40px" class="md-hue-1" ng-dblclick="vm.openFromLeft()">               
                    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">                 
                        <h1 >{{card.view.name }}</h1>                 
                        <md-menu >                   
                            <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">                     
                                <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>                   
                            </md-button>                   
                            <md-menu-content >                     
                                <md-menu-item ng-repeat="view in vm.views" >                       
                                    <md-button ng-click="card.view=view" class="md-hue-2" >{{view.name}}</md-button>                     
                                </md-menu-item>                   
                            </md-menu-content>                 
                        </md-menu>               
                    </div>             
                </md-toolbar>             
                <md-card-content flex class="cardcontent"  >               
                    <sdiv-panel card={{card.view.element}} view={{card.name}}_4 >               
                    </sdiv-panel>             
                </md-card-content>           
            </md-card>         
        </div>       
    </div>     
    <div ng-hide="vm.multipleview"  >       
        <md-content layout-fill>         
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom >           
                <div ng-repeat="cardrow in vm.cards">           
                    <md-tab  ng-repeat="card in cardrow " label="{{ card.view.name }}">             
                        <!--<md-tab  ng-repeat="card in vm.tabtable " label="{{ card.name }}">-->             
                        <md-content layout-fill="" flex=""  style="margin-top: 10px" >               
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px" >                 
                                <sdiv-panel card={{card.view.element}}  view={{card.name}}_1 ></sdiv-panel>               
                            </div>             
                        </md-content>           
                    </md-tab>           
                </div>         
            </md-tabs>       
        </md-content>     
    </div>   
</md-content>
```

Comment: Can you provide any implementation of your directive and an example of the use, please ?

Comment: you should use isolate scope for the directive and for html use transclude. i hope it helps

Comment: i add the code like an answer. thanks

Comment: yeh i am using it in my directive but it dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is my directive : 
(function() {
  'use strict';

angular.module('sdivMaterial.panel')
   .directive(
     'sdivPanel', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: false,
      scope : {
        card: "@",
        view:"@"
      },
      template: "",
      link: function postLink($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $attr.$observe('card', function(data) {
          console.log("Updated data ", $scope.card, " : ", $scope.view);
          var html = $scope.card;
          $element.html(html);
          $compile($element.contents())($scope);
        }, true);
      }
    }
  })
})();

an example of my main.html :
  
      
        
          
            
              
                {{card.view.name }}
                
                  
                    more_vert
                  
                  
                    
                      {{view.name}}
                    
                  
                
              
            
            
              
              
            
          
        
      
    
      
        
          
          
            -->

Answer (score 0):

Here is my directive :

```
    (function() {'use strict';
    angular.module('sdivMaterial.panel')
    .directive(
    'sdivPanel', function($compile) {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: false,
    scope : {
      card: "@",
      view:"@"
    },
     template: "",
     link: function postLink($scope, $element, $attr) {
     $attr.$observe('card', function(data) {
      console.log("Updated data ", $scope.card, " : ", $scope.view);
      var html = $scope.card;
      $element.html(html);
      $compile($element.contents())($scope);
     }, true);
   }
  }
 })
})();
```